# What are the disadvanges and advantages of using NoCount in Reporting Services?

Tags: ssrs-2008

What are the advantages and disadvanges of using the Set NOCount on TSQL for Reporting Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Advantages:**

- You avoid unnecessary processing to return the row counts.

**Disadvantages:**

- You drive yourself crazy trying to micro-optimize your report.